# Salesforce SDK -Unable to resolve org.apache.http.* APIs with Android 6.0 build target

Tags: android, eclipse, salesforce, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am getting following error when I set Android 6.0 as Project Build target for SalesforceSDK 3.3.0.

[image]

And I guess because of this [Changes in Android 6.0](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html)

[image]

**As I am working on Eclipse - build.gradle file solution does't work.**

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Android SDK you will find a folder like this:

```
/home/raditha/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-23/optional/
```

In it exists a file named `org.apache.http.legacy.jar` copy it in your projects libs folder, right click and add to build path. You might also need to goto the order and export tab and mark for export.

Comment: Awesome yar.. Thank you veeery much.. Its works.And unfortunately I can  up only once :) :) ...